# Jest mock unnable to pick up error throw?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have some code that calls an api. I am testing the functionality that is nested in try catches, and checking the correct behaviour happens when I throw an error with certain values.

```
async function createDeployment(namespace, config, name) {
  try {
    await k8sDeploymentApi.createNamespacedDeployment(namespace, config, true);
    console.log('Successful deployment');
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    if (e.response.statusCode === HTTP_CONFLICT) {
      try {
        await k8sDeploymentApi.replaceNamespacedDeployment(name, namespace, config, true);
        console.log('Successfully replaced deployment');
        return Promise.resolve(true);
      } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(e);
  }
}
```

I am mocking out the api calls node module here

```
var mockListNamespacedIngress;
var mockCreateNamespacedDeployment;
var mockReplaceNamespacedDeployment;
jest.mock('@kubernetes/client-node', () => {
  mockListNamespacedIngress = jest.fn();
  mockCreateNamespacedDeployment = jest.fn();
  mockReplaceNamespacedDeployment = jest.fn();
  return {
    KubeConfig: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      loadFromCluster: jest.fn(),
      loadFromDefault: jest.fn(),
      makeApiClient: () => ({
        listNamespacedIngress: mockListNamespacedIngress,
        createNamespacedDeployment: mockCreateNamespacedDeployment,
        replaceNamespacedDeployment: mockReplaceNamespacedDeployment,
      }),
    })),
  };
});
```

And running the test here

```
    it.only('Should return a log of success if replaced deployment resolves', async () => {
      mockCreateNamespacedDeployment.mockRejectedValueOnce(() =>
        Promise.reject(new Error({ response: { statusCode: 409 } })),
      );

      mockReplaceNamespacedDeployment.mockResolvedValueOnce(true);

      // When
      await expect(createDeployment()).resolves.toEqual(true);
    });
```

However on the console.log(JSON.stringify(e)), I am only ever getting undefined coming back. So it does seem to throw the error, but gives no error object from the catch. Here is my full stacktrace

```
 ● Kubernetes deployment script tests › Kubernetes Calls › Should return a log of success if replaced deployment resolves

    expect(received).resolves.toEqual()

    Received promise rejected instead of resolved
    Rejected to value: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined]

      143 |
      144 |       // When
    > 145 |       await expect(createDeployment()).resolves.toEqual(true);
          |             ^
      146 |     });
      147 |   });
      148 |

      at expect (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:134:15)
      at Object.it.only (src/__tests__/index.test.js:145:13)

  console.log
    Successful deployment

      at createDeployment (src/index.js:73:13)

  console.log
    undefined

      at createDeployment (src/index.js:76:13)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can mock an async function throwing an Error like this

```
mockCreateNamespacedDeployment.mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error({ response: { statusCode: 409 } });
```

and then you can expect

```
await expect(createDeployment()).rejects.toThrow();
```

---

Btw in your `async` function you can replace all of the

```
- Promise.resolve(xxx)
+ return xxx

// and
- Promise.reject(xxx)
+ throw xxx
```

Comment: When I do this, I still get the console.log of 'successful deployment' and no value in the 'e' variable created in catch(e), as opposed to when I run the code normally, where it breaks into the catch when createNamespacedDeployment errors with a 409 http statuscode.